# How to create a coconut tree trunk?

Tags: material-selection, technique-selection, miniatures

For one of my art hobby projects, I want to create a miniature coconut tree trunk closely resembling an actual coconut tree. Below is a close-up image for reference:

[image: photograph of coconut tree]

I am thinking of using some kind of leather or fabric which will be put around a flexible tube. I'm looking for some material that will be flexible enough to bend along with the inner tube to a certain degree. However, I'm not sure how to get the leather/fabric resemble the trunk texture.

If someone has some ideas for it, that would be immensely helpful.

I appreciate the responses in advance.

Comment: How big should the finished tree be? Depending on the size other materials might be viable or completely out of scale.

Comment: @Elmy, I want it to have a diameter of not more than an inch. Length could go to as much as a meter.

Answer (score 0):

Look at textured faux leathers, they come in a huge variety of patterns and colors. The gator skin ones look fairly similar to the tree bark in your photo.